# AMPScript not working in CloudPages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need to update a Salesforce using CloudPages but it is erroring out because of the AMPScript that I have written. Below is my code. When I view the page I get 500 Internal Server error

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
%%[

var @sflead, @Subskey 
set @sflead = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Department_Contact__c','a1V2C000000Gyxxxx','Deactivate__c','true') 

]%%
<head>
</head>
<body>
 HELLO HELLO
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your page display without the AMPScript? Is your page and/or microsite published?

Comment: Yes it works without the AMPScript and it is published also ..

Comment: The same AMPScript works perfectly in an email

Comment: Did you fix your problem with UpdateSingleSalesforceObject on a CloudPage ? I have the same problem, am on touch with Marketing Cloud support, but they can't find a solution in this problem. Thank you for your answer and good luck with that point if you're on same state than me...

Comment: No I couldn't :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does record exist in `Department_Contact__c` with an `ID` of `a1V2C000000Gyxxxx`?  Is `True` a valid value for the `Deactivate__c` field?

I would recommend wrapping the AMPScript function in a SSJS try/catch statement and then output the error.  You should get a more descriptive error than a generic 500 Internal Server error.

Here's an example of a SSJS try/catch statement used in conjunction with AMPScript.

```
<script runat='server'>
  Platform.Load('Core','1.1.1');
  try {
</script>  

%%[
var @sflead, @Subskey 
set @sflead =     UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Department_Contact__c','a1V2C000000Gyxxxx','Deactivate__c','true') 
]%%

<script runat='server'>
  } 
  catch(e) {
    Write(Stringify(e));
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi David, am trying to update a custom object (department_contact) ..

Comment: Also, how do I invoke this SSJS from a landing page in Cloudpages?

Comment: The SSJS code can be inline along with your HTML and AMPScript.

Comment: p.s.  The UpdateSingleSalesforceObject() function only works if SFMC has been integrated with a Salesforce ORG using the Marketing Cloud Connector.  I assume this has already been done.

Answer (score 1):

I've never been able to get the SSJS try catch statement to work for me in CloudPages. I just get the 500 Server Error.

Here's a solution to debug:

1. Create a new Paste HTML email
2. Paste the HTML from the CloudPage in the text area and click **Save**
3. Click on the Text tab and remove the AMPscript code block (to prevent the code from executing twice when previewing)
4. Click **Send Preview**
5. Select **All Subscribers**
6. Select any Subscriber
7. Click **Generate Preview**

The AMPscript error will be displayed on the page.

Comment: The AMPScript is working perfectly in email but not in Cloudpages ..

Comment: @ManeeshGupta, that's bizarre. Are you using the same Business Unit? Are you waiting for a sufficient time for the change to propagate across the CDN after publishing? Something else I would try is to drop your AMPscript into a ContentArea then include it in the CloudPage using the [ContentArea()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/content/ContentArea.html) AMPscript function, so any changes you make to the ContentArea will be immediately reflected on your CloudPage, which is a lot quicker than waiting for the updated page to propagate.