# AMPScript on click of a button to update Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect, cloudpage

We have a Custom Preference Center built in CloudPages. On the click on 'Update Preferences' button, I want to save the updated preferences in Salesforce.
Is this possible using AMPScript?

We have Marketing Cloud Connect already set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the Salesforce AMPScript functions:

- [**RetrieveSalesforceObjects()**](https://ampscript.guide/retrievesalesforceobjects)
- [**UpdateSingleSalesforceObject()**](https://ampscript.guide/UpdateSingleSalesforceObject)

There are some good tips in the responses to [**your previous question**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/141302/5202) on this topic.

Comment: Yes Adam I did check that but last time I wasn't able to get it working. Also, my understanding is that AMPScript is a server side thing .. and click of button is client-side .. so not so sure whether it can really work or not ..

Comment: Yes you can do it with a form post to the same page.